# External monitor not detected

Tags: laptop, monitors, endeavouros

I've installed XFCE EndeavourOS on my work laptop. Long story short, the laptop does not currently detect external monitor, and I need to get this fixed.

Here's more details - The laptop's video cards include both an Intel HD Graphics 530, and an Nvidia Quadro M1000M. At first, after a clean install of EndeavourOS, the external monitor was detected and able to be used. However, there was screen tearing and the nvidia driver was not installed. So I installed the nvidia driver, causing the computer to boot to a black screen with blinking cursor. This was fixed by deleting the files in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/. Logging in after this, the screen tearing was fixed, but the external monitor is no longer detected. So I uninstalled the nvidia driver, but the external monitor still cannot be detected.

Here is some diagnostic information:

Every time I plug in the external monitor a few lines get added to the xorg log. You can see several replugs recorded below:

```
[   196.173] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.70  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[   341.541] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1191
[   341.541] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   341.541] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.70  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[   347.373] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1191
[   347.374] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   347.374] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.70  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
[   433.397] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 1191
[   433.397] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   433.397] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.70  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 +hsync -vsync (66.7 kHz eP)
```

xrandr doesn't see the monitor. It has the same output regardless of whether the monitor is plugged in. See below:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/SQ2qKxRs) is a paste of my Xorg.0.log

What next steps might help me diagnose and resolve this issue?

Comment: Although I consider it more of a work-around than a solution, installing the open source xf86 nouveau drivers (as opposed to the proprietary drivers) has caused the external monitor to work again

Comment: Also, with the open source drivers, I still get screen tearing

Comment: Disabling, in the bios, the integrated intel graphics fixed this issue, but is not a good solution.

Comment: Is the external monitor connected via Thunderbolt or a different connector? I've found Thunderbolt to be a little trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar setup on Arch, I've noticed that it doesn't always autoload correct drivers when starting Xorg. Make sure you have loaded:

```
nvidia-modeset
nvidia-drm
nvidia
```

before launching Xorg.